# Is it possible to calculate the standard deviation of a set that is built from moving averages?

Tags: standard-deviation, moving-average

Hope you are all doing fine.

I need to calculate the probability of the performance of a X player increasing or decreasing in time.

For each ball the X player kicks, he can either score (1) or miss (0).

So I'll calculate the performance simply by averaging the set (lets call points-set). If he scores 10 times of 15, I'll give him a 0,66 score, and so on.

This creates another set (let's call avg-set), a set of the moving averages of the player.

So I was wondering: is it possible for me to calculate the standard deviation of the avg-set?

I'm in doubt as, of course, each element of the avg-set can't be called independent of the previous one. At least I think so.

And if it is not possible to calculate the standard deviation, how can I estimate the probability of change in the avg-set?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! Nothing wrong with calculating the standard deviation since it does not require any prerequisite regarding the way your data is generated. It will give you a single value reflecting how variable that player's performance. However, if you are eager to monitor that player's progression over time, a better idea would be calculating the means and standard deviations on each moving window segment. In this way, you can observe both mean performance and its deviation. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! This was a key information for me.